# Simple React Component Doesn't Appear

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to React. I am trying to create simple react configuration with webpack and babel. But none of my tries succeed. When i run `npm start`,then enter http://localhost:3333 from browser, an empty page appears. I can see just the title of the page. What do i miss?

Here my codes.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 entry: './main.js',
 output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'index.js'
 },
 devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
 },
 module: {
    loaders: 
    [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['react','es2015']
        }
    }]
 }
}
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "es6-react-setup",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.3",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.0"
},
"description": ""
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Setup</title>     
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementbyId('app'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>Hello</div>
    }
}

export default App
```

EDIT:

I delete index.js and node_modules. After that i installed react react-dom babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-react. Then below package.json appears. I also run `webpack` command to produce index.js

```
{
  "name": "es6-react-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "nw": "webpack --progress --profile --colors"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you run webpack? Does `index.js` exist? Did you install the presets (they don't appear in your package.json)?

Comment: Thank you Felix. I edited the post. But page is still empty.

Comment: where main.js is called ? is it called anywhere ?

Comment: Is it in the webpack.config.js? Does `entry` part indicate that? Is there any place to call main.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your still missing

```js
"webpack": "^1.8.5",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.4.7"
```

from your dependencies.

Comment: I add  "webpack": "^1.12.9",    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0" with install npm install command. But still same.

Comment: Add  "nw": "webpack --progress --profile --colors"  to scripts and try npm run nw. You should get some feedback on webpacks' progress.

Comment: `1055ms build modules      
5ms seal 
8ms optimize 
9ms hashing 
22ms create chunk assets
3ms additional chunk assets 
0ms optimize chunk assets 
1ms optimize assets 
28ms emit
Hash: 9c976391f9adba70c8b3
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 1169ms
   Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  679 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 160 hidden modules`
After i run nw, i get above lines.

Comment: Did you open the developer tools in your browser?

Comment: After i open the developer tools i see `document.getElementbyId` is not a function. For sure it can be `document.getElementById`. And it works now. Sorry for this silly mistake :(. Thank you for your helps Janaka.